# Is it possible to restrict MySQL IP and Port on a Public REST API without affecting its open access to all?

Tags: mysql

We currently have a Public API to be used by our Business' current and future clients. Due to flexibility purposes and capability for our client's systems to interface with ours, we currently have our MySQL Database IP and Port on Wild Card access so as to not encounter any restricted access issues.

Question is, due to security concerns, would it be possible to restrict the MySQL Database's Server IP and Port to not be accessed directly by third party clients but only via the Public API? My instinct says no, but I don't have much experience in the way of Public APIs nor Public Access.

When an API User sends a query on our database, does it identify it via the API Host's IP (our servers?), or via the Client Computer's IP?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an API, why do you need to expose mysql?

Comment: @EliasSoares the api needs to do some query calls to the database. like i said, i'm not really experienced with public api and databases, so i don't know the practices to be done.

Comment: The API do the queries to database, not the API consumer. So the database don't need to be public, just need to be accessible by the API server.

Answer (score 1):

It's considered a bad security risk to expose MySQL's port directly to external clients. MySQL supports TLS but doesn't enforce it by default. So you're at risk of unauthorized clients invading.

For this reason, it's much safer and more recommended to run your own API server, as you mentioned. The API server is the only one allowed to connect to MySQL. Typically network routing is configured to prevent *any* contact to the database server except from the API server.

MySQL would therefore know nothing about the client's IP address. As far as MySQL is concerned, your API server is the only IP address it knows about.

The client IP address would be known by your API server and http server, and if you have load balancers or firewalls, those too.

The "users" associated with your third-party clients aren't necessarily mapped to distinct users in the MySQL authentication system. Actually, it's more typical that the API server uses a single MySQL user to authenticate all clients. Once connected to the database, your code would look up the client's "user" as a further authentication step. In other words, you would store a table in your own database with user credentials, and you would implement code to check passwords and so on. This is distinct from MySQL's own authentication system.

Alternatively, you could write your API service to use SAML or Oauth2 or equivalent federated authentication.  The API service would still need to authenticate to MySQL, but the client's identity would be provided by the Oauth2 authentication.